# Modelbinding multiple properties SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, websocket, signalr

I've been trying out SignalR in a new project and I've ran into an issue when it comes to modelbinding.

My Javascript hub:

```
state.socket?.invoke(SocketInvoke.submitAnswer, 1, 2, 3, [4,5,6]);
```

My method:

```
public async Task SubmitAnswer(int gameId, int quizId, int questionId, int[] optionIds)
```

But this does not seem to work. I tried changing it up to:

```
 const answer = {
            GameId: 1,
            QuizId: 2,
            QuestionId: 3,
            OptionIds: [4,5,6]
        }
state.socket?.invoke(SocketInvoke.submitAnswer, answer);

public async Task SubmitAnswer(SubmittedAnswerViewModel answer)

public class SubmittedAnswerViewModel
{
 public int GameId { get; set; }
 public int QuizId { get; set; }
 public int QuestionId { get; set; }
 public int[] OptionIds { get; set; }
     
}
```

I also tried changing the OptionIds to a List, as well as just turning it to an int to see if the array of ints was the issue, but it was not. In the end I was wondering if I had a typo somewhere in my calls, so I changed the params to just a single string and that successfully binded.

Does anyone know why this wont bind? I feel like the answer is probably obvious, but I just can't see it.

Thanks for reading and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually...

I was doing Task.Delay() inside the methods, effectively leaving my hook pending and waiting for a response. I thought it'd be a nice way to ensure to send questions exactly at the right time, and make it harder to tinker with time limits etc.

In retrospect it seems very obvious, but I only found out this was the cause because I left a breakpoint up while googling for solutions and it my VSC suddenly started blinking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `SocketInvoke.submitAnswer` returns the string "submitAnswer"?
Your code works when I try it with this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-signalr-client-code

Comment: Hello and thank you for replying.

Yes, because I tried altering my method to receive just a string parameter, and then sent a single string to it, and it received that string, but when I try sending multiple parameters like this, it does not work.

Comment: Can you activate and post the server logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0#server-side-logging)? 
What does the client say/throw? Is it `Error: Failed to invoke 'submitAnswer' due to an error on the server. InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked.`? (Enable this `services.AddSignalR(o => { o.EnableDetailedErrors = true; });` in your Startup.cs)